# Entity Framework mapear algunas propiedades

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Tengo una base de datos sqlserver del cual genero los modelos correspondientes con EF. El problema surge porque una tabla de la base de datos por ejemplo users es dinámica, puede ser que un registro aparezca o no(Dirección).

TABLA USERS con registros: ID, Nombre,Apellido pero Direccion puede ser que no aparezca en la tabla.

El problema viene en mapear el objeto User con sus propiedades correspondientes ID,Nombre,Apellido, Dirección. A ver si existe algún método que mapee la propiedad "dirección" en el caso que exista en la tabla, sino que cree el objeto user sin la propiedad dirección. Es necesario que el modelo tenga todas las propiedades igual que los registros de la tabla?

**EDIT**: Lo que me pasa en realidad es que un servidor puede tener diferentes versiones de un proyecto de una base de datos. En la primera versión no esta definido la dirección, puede ser que en otro servidor tenga una nueva versión del proyecto y sí este en la tabla. Luego tengo una api que el cliente decide en que servidor conectarse ahí surge el problema que el cliente no sabe en que versión se conecta del proyecto pero tengo que generar el modelo cliente en función de si esta la columna en la BD o no esta

Answer (score 1):

La verdad lo que planteas no tiene mucho sentido, la columan la defines o no la defines, despues si es un dato opcional podrias hacer que sea nullable

El mapping de EF no puede ser dinamico porque se supone que la estructura de la db es fija y definida por el schema de la db

Remarco, si el valor de la columan es opcional definelo para que permita nulos, entonces no necesitaras asignarlo si para un suario no tienes ese info

Comment: Lo que me pasa en realidad es que un servidor puede tener diferentes versiones de un proyecto de una base de datos. En la primera versión no esta definido la dirección, puede ser que en otro servidor tenga una nueva versión del proyecto y sí este en la tabla. Luego tengo una api que el cliente decide en que servidor conectarse ahí surge el problema que el cliente no sabe en que versión se conecta del proyecto pero tengo que generar el modelo cliente en función de si esta la columna en la BD  o no esta.

Comment: pero este problema no lo resuelves con EF, sino con la capa de perssitencia. Si usas el patron Repository podrias tener varias versiones de este entonces contarias con un repository que uses un mapping de EF con este campo y otra version que no lo tanga, por configuracion podrias indicar que cargue una implementacion u otra segun a cual db se quiera conectar. EF no te resuelve lo que plantes sino que debe ser tu arquitectura

Comment: A la hora de hacer el mapping entonces tendría que generar 2 entidades diferentes no? Entiendo yo por el patrón Repository genérico que tengo las operaciones CRUD, es ahí donde tendría que haber un dbcontext diferente según la versión? Seria mucho pedir un pequeño ejemplo gracias.

Comment: exacto tendras dos dbcontext diferentes, pero puedes poner estos en proyectos class library distintos segun cada version. Cada Repository usara el que corresponde para persistir o no los campos que varien por version. Seguramente las entidades tambien difieran. De esta forma solo cambiarias la persistencia cuando tengas diferencias en la db